# MATLAB - Error using interp1>reshapeAndSortXandV X and V must be of the same length

Tags: matlab, diff, acceleration

I geht this error message when I try to derive my acceleration of the car. I think there is a size problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
The data is measured from a car.

```
meas.jerk.data = diff(meas.acc.data);
meas.jerk.time = meas.acc.time;
```

I think I have to do  something like this but I really don't know.

```
size(diff(meas.acc.data)) = size(meas.acc.data)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question seems vague and incomplete. The statement `size(diff(meas.acc.data)) = size(meas.acc.data)` makes no sense, as you use the assignment operarator `=` to the `size` function. An equality comparison is made with `==`, but `size` returns an array. Also, what you mean by derive? Numerical differentiation? Or do you have the acceleration already on the `meas.acc.data` variable? What you want to do?

Comment: I want to plot the jerk from the acceleration. I know that diff(meas.acc.data) looses one dimension from his size and thats why its not correct.

Comment: Check the [gradient](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function. Aproximate your derivative with a finite difference, `jerk=grad(acceleration)./grad(time)`